# Jackson Deserialiser ignoring @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP) annotation on field, always sets null values

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

When a json request is sent to create a new Entity via our internal API the Jackson Json deserializer always sets the countryGroup as null even though the field is annotated with @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP). This throws an exception when the entity is validated ( as field is annotated with @NotNull) before committed to the DB by Spring/Hibernate.

(I have simplified the request and entity to make it easier to understand)

request looks like:

```
{
     //...other fields in actual entity
     "countryGroup": null
}
```

with an entity class defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class Entity{

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //...other fields in actual entity

    @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "country_group", length = 64)
    private String countryGroup = "";// default value
    
    public String getCountryGroup() {
        return countryGroup;
    }
 }
```

As previously mentioned there are other fields being set properly but the `countryGroup` filed always gets set to null. We are using Jackson 2.9 so this should be supported. As far as I can see I have set the annotation correctly, could there any other configuration that could be overriding this? Or some other reason as to why this does not work.

I have tried to debug and I can see the default `""` value for `countryGroup` set by the default constructor but this is always overridden when the property exists in the json object, if it is not in the json it keep the default value.

[EDIT] Fixed typo

Comment: `"countryGroup": null` and `private String currencyGroup = "";`. You see the difference?

Comment: Atribute in example json is `countryGroup`, while field in entity `currencyGroup`. Typo in question, or???

Comment: Yep typo they should all be the same. Corrected (actually I have 2 fields with the same issue one is currency and the other is country)

Comment: Can you add your object mapper config? I can't reproduce the issue locally with basic configuration.

Comment: @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP), use it on a setter, it shall work